# Using RDA on a Desktop Application?

Tags: .net-3.5, sql-server-ce, rda

I have a .NET 3.5 Compact Framework project that uses RDA for moving data between its mobile device's local SqlCe database and a remote MSSql-2008 server(it uses RDA Push and Pull).

The server machine a virtual directory with sqlcesa35.dll (v3.5.5386.0) setup for RDA.
We usually install these cabs on the mobile devices and the RDA process does not have any problems:
sqlce.wce5.armv4i.cab
sqlce.repl.wce5.armv4i.cab

Now I am trying to run this application as a desktop application.  RDA Pull (download) has been working well.  But the RDA Push (upload) is giving me some problems.

This is the exception that I get on the desktop application when I try to use RDA Push:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
>
> The Client Agent and Server Agent component versions are incompatible. The compatible versions are: Client Agent versions 3.0 and 3.5 with Server Agent versions 3.5 and Client Agent version 3.5 with Server Agent version 3.5. Re-install the replication components with the matching versions for client and server agents. [ 35,30,Client Agent version = ,Server Agent version =  ]

I have tried copying the file

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop\SqlServerCe.dll (v3.5.5692.0)

to bin\debug

I have also tried copying another version of SqlServerCe.dll (v3.0.5206.0) to bin\debug.  But this just gives me a slightly different exception:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
>    [ 35,30 ]

Is there a different setup or any different dlls that I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help, I had same problem yesterday, after installing newer version of server agent it finally works.

Neven
(nprelog at gmail.com)

SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 released!
SQL Server Compact 3.5 (build 3.5.8080.0) has been released to web.

SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 includes a host of new features including the following:

Support for the Transact-SQL Editor in Visual Studio 2010 that can be used to run free-text T-SQL queries and to view query show-plans for optimizing queries.
Exposes the Change Tracking feature as an application programming interface (API), namely, System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeChangeTracking. The new Change Tracking API provides the ability to configure, enable, and disable change tracking on a table, and to access the change tracking data for the table.
New assembly versioning support and directory structure that enables the SQL Server Compact applications that use private deployment to load SQL Server Compact assemblies from within the application folder if they are of a higher version than that in the global assembly cache (GAC).
Support added for deploying the 64-bit version of SQL Server Compact using the ClickOnce deployment.
Synchronization Services for ADO.NET v1.0 providing the ability to synchronize data from disparate sources over two-tier, N-tier, and service-based architectures.

- and the product team has more details here: 
  Downloads:

Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 Server Tools 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5DEEC9D5-C216-446E-A003-5D6026AD19B3&displaylang=en

Comment: This worked for me.  

After I installed the SP2, I just had to rerun the "Configure Web Synchronization Wizard" from --- Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5\Configure Web Synchronization Wizard ---
shortcut to --- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\sync\SQL\ConnWiz.exe ---

After that, the Desktop was able to do normal RDA Push and Pull.

Thanks.